# Why the using block of enumerateChildNodes of SKNode escaping?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

The signature of the `enumerateChildNodes` method of `SKNode` is:

```
func enumerateChildNodes(
    withName name: String, 
    using block: @escaping (SKNode, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

Why the `block` parameter is marked as `@escaping`? Surely when the call of `enumerateChildNodes` finishes, the block will be executed on all the child nodes with the given name, right?

Comment: The `@escaping` put there means that the closure parameter may escape

Comment: Thank you for commenting, @AlessandroOrnano. But what I don't understand is why make the closure parameter escaping?